# NHibernate.dll' is not trusted issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a project on my local machine to learn NHibernate with ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Using this tutorial I get the following error message when running my tests.  I can compile successfully.

http://forerunnerg34.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/using-asp-net-mvc-and-nhibernate-part-1/#comment-71

Failed to queue test run Test Run deployment issue: The location of the file or directory 'd:\websites\test\test\test.tests\bin\debug\NHibernate.dll' is not trusted.

I've added a project reference to my test.tests project for Core.  Let me know if you need more as I realise this is probably a vague, I'm not sure what will help.  I have a solution with 4 projects: Core, Infrastructure, Test and Test.Tests.  'Tests' is the ASP.NET project.

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you downloaded the assembly from untrusted source Windows might have blocked it. Try unblocking NHibernate.dll:

[image]

Comment: thank you.  This isnt actually a problem now where I am in getting this working.  I'll remember this if I experience that problem again.  Many thanks,